# Creating a Bin column in Postgres to check an integer and return a string

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I have a large data set in a Postgres db and need to generate a field that groups rows into a respective bin for "0-100", "101-200", "201-300", etc. all the way up to nearly 5000. I am aware that I could manually update each row and produce a line of code for each bin like this:

```
update test
   set testgroup = '0-100' where testint >= 1 and distance < 100;
```

I really would like to figure out a more efficient way to do this, open to anything and everything! The main goal is to look at the integer in this 'testint' column and then if it is in between 1-100 return in the testgroup column "0-100".

Comment: Do you have a unique identifier on each row?

Comment: in your example code, shouldn't the comparison variables be the same? i.e. testint >=1 and testint < 100

Comment: Sorry that was a typo. Not really wanting to write that line and manually update it 50 times as well. The rows do have unique identifiers.

Answer (score 4):

Use the `width_bucket` function. See the [the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-math.html), but here is a short version of the syntax:

```
width_bucket(a, LBound, UBound, num_bins)
```

To get it to work properly for your bins, I have to add 1 to UBound. Some examples:

`select width_bucket( 1, 0, 5001, 50)` gives 1
`select width_bucket(100, 0, 5001,  0)` gives 1
`select width_bucket(101, 0, 5001, 50)` gives 2
`select width_bucket(4900, 0, 5001, 50)` gives 49
`select width_bucket(4901, 0, 5001, 50)` gives 50

So that works as expected. Next we need to generate the proper string. Pseudo format is

```
(width_bucket - 1)*100 || '-' || (width_bucket)*100
```

Where || is the SQL concatenation operator. Using the first example from before:

```
select (width_bucket(1, 0, 5001, 50)-1)*100 || ' - ' || width_bucket(1, 0, 5001, 50)*100
```

gives `'0 - 100'`

Sweet. Now putting it all together. First make a sandbox table you can use for testing. This will be a copy or partial copy of your data:

```
CREATE TABLE test
AS
SELECT * 
FROM original_table
```

Then add the new column to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE test
  ADD COLUMN testgroup text
```

Now the UPDATE statement:

```
UPDATE test
   SET testgroup = width_bucket(testint, 0, 5001, 50)-1)*100 || ' - ' || 
                   width_bucket(testint, 0, 5001, 50)*100
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `generate_series` to generate numbers from 0 to 50, and then to select the data between the generated values * 100 and the next generated value * 100. The same principle is used to build the bin name.

```sql
UPDATE test
SET testgroup = (x*100)+1 || '-' || (x+1)*100
FROM generate_series(0,50) f(x)
WHERE testint > (x*100) 
  AND testint <= ((x+1)*100);
```

http://rextester.com/FXIS37706

Comment: Hi, I am using a similar binning method and found your code useful. Although I don't seem to understand it well enough. The part about "FROM generate_series(0,50) f(x)". While I understand the logic I am not able to get the syntax. What does f(x) mean here - a function ? or another dataset like generate_series(0,50)

Comment: @KanduriR the `f` is the table alias for the output, the `(x)` is used to rename the columns. Here since the output of `generate_series` is a single column, it doesn't really add much. Let's say you have a table `mytable` with 3 columns `x, y, z`,  you can do `select * from mytable a(a,b,c)` and the columns will be shown as `a,b,c`, not `x,y,z`

Comment: Ok understand now. Thank you @JGH. Is this notation ```mytable a(a,b,c)``` is specific to postgres or is this a generic notation in SQL language ?